# plotting US heat map with text

Tags: r, plot, maps

Inputs:

```
Percent.Turnout  US.State
70               CA
80               NM
76               RI
```

I have data for each of the 50 states in the US. Also, the state abbreviation for US.State is consistent with the abbreviations in the function state.abb

I would like to create a US map where the Percent.Turnout is printed on each state. Furthermore, using the ColorBrewer package, I would like to color each state based on its Percent.Turnout relative to other states.

I am not very familiar with ggplot syntax, so suggestions in base R would be appreciated (if feasible)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use `ggplot2`, then the major thing that you need to do is map the state abbreviation column to the full state name in lower case (For this, you can use `state.name`, but make sure to apply `tolower()` on it to get it in the right format).

From there, it's simply a matter of joining your dataset to the state's geospatial information and plotting the data. The following segment of code takes you through that step by step:

```
# First, we need the ggplot2 library:
> library(ggplot2)
# We load the geospatial data for the states
# (there are more options to the map_data function, 
# if you are intrested in taking a look).
> states <- map_data("state")
# Here I'm creating a sample dataset like yours. 
# The dataset will have 2 columns: The region (or state)
# and a number that will represent the value that you
# want to plot (here the value is just the numerical order of the states).
> sim_data <- data.frame(region=unique(states$region), Percent.Turnout=match(unique(states$region), unique(states$region)))
# Then we merge our dataset with the geospatial data:
> sim_data_geo <- merge(states, sim_data, by="region")
# The following should give us the plot without the numbers: 
> qplot(long, lat, data=sim_data_geo, geom="polygon", fill=Percent.Turnout, group=group)
```

This is the output of the segment of code above:

[image]

Now, you said you'd like to also add the value `Percent.Turnout` to the map. Here, we need to find the center point of the various states. You can calculate that from the geospatial data that we retrieved above (in the `states` dataframe), but the results won't look very impressive. Thankfully, R has the values for the centers of the states already calculated for us, and we can leverage that, as follows:

```
# We'll use the state.center list to tell us where exactly
# the center of the state is.
> snames <- data.frame(region=tolower(state.name), long=state.center$x, lat=state.center$y)
# Then again, we need to join our original dataset 
# to get the value that should be printed at the center.
> snames <- merge(snames, sim_data, by="region")
# And finally, to put everything together: 
> ggplot(sim_data_geo, aes(long, lat)) + geom_polygon(aes(group=group, fill=Percent.Turnout)) + geom_text(data=snames, aes(long, lat, label=Percent.Turnout))
```

And this is the output of the the last statement above:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful answer! One small issue I have is that there is some blank whitespace within California and Colorado, as well as some other states. Would you know why that would be?

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of what you're seeing? Do the gaps you're describing match any of the regions in this image (http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/maps-package.PNG)? If yes, then perhaps the `states` dataset is missing some of the sub-regions for some reason.

Comment: I have added a screenshot as an edit to my question. There are two rather sizable gaps that stand out.

Comment: Are you sure you that you specified the `group` argument in `qplot`  or `geom_polygon`? If you don't specify the `group` argument, the map will have gaps similar to the ones you're seeing. If you did specify the `group` argument, then I'll need to see the segment of code that you used to generate the plot in order to understand why this is happening. It'd also be helpful to know what version of R and ggplot2 you're working with. After you load the ggplot2 library, you can run the command `sessionInfo()` to get that. Mine is: `R version 3.1.2    maps_2.3-9    ggplot2_1.0.0`.